# Angular, call new constructor inside a $get (in provider)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use a function inside  .provider as a constructor, but can't seem to call a new constructor on it when it's inside the $get.

So I have my provider like -

```
 this.$get = $get;
    $get.$inject = ['checkUrl', '$log', '$location'];

    function $get(checkUrl, $log, $location) {
        return {

            moduleCon: function(name, cb) {
                    //my constructor function
                }

            }
```

And if i inject it and call

```
   new  myProvider.$get().moduleCon("name", "cb");
```

I get back an injector error.

But if i put it outside the get, it works like this

```
   (inside the provider above the $get)
    this.moduleCon = function(name, cb) {
                    //my constructor function
                }
```

I have to put a .this, but then I can call

```
   new myProvider.moduleCon("name","cb");
```

And it works fine. Is there a way to expose it in the $get as a constructor as I am using here? Thanks!

Comment: can you show the entire code of the provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have is interpreted as

```
(new myProvider.$get()).moduleCon("name", "cb");
```

which doesn't do what you want. You'll need to do

```
new (myProvider.$get().moduleCon)("name", "cb"); // or
new (myProvider.$get()).moduleCon("name", "cb");
```

explictly, but I can only recommend against creating constructor functions on the fly.

Comment: This ended up working, is there any reason it interprets it like that? Thanks.

Comment: Well, that's just how the language works. `new` is applied to the first function call it sees.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `myProvider` you are actually calling that `$get` function. Under the hood, there is this line that calls the injector's `invoke` method:

```
instanceInjector.invoke(provider.$get, provider, undefined, serviceName);
```

There are a lot of details involved, but the bottom line is that `myProvider` *is* the returned value from the `$get` function you defined. What you were trying to do would work if you wrote it like this:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, myProvider) {
  myProvider.$get();
});

app.provider('myProvider', function() {
  this.$get = function(){
    return {
      $get: function(){console.log('something isn\'t right here...')}
    }
  };
});
```

Doing this obviously doesn't make any sense but I hope it helps you understand how this works a bit better. `$get` is what you use to "get" whatever the provider is providing. A `factory` recipe is in fact just a `provider` whose `$get` method is the function passed to the `app.factory` method:

```
function factory(name, factoryFn) {
    return provider(name, { $get: factoryFn });
}
```